# Electron fails on build with exit code 255

Tags: node.js, macos, electron, electron-builder

sorry for the "not so specific title" :smiley:
i'm trying to pack my application with electron-build, but it keep me blocking the build, throwing this error:

```
Error: /usr/local/Cellar/node/7.7.4/bin/node exited with code 1
Output:

> ursa@0.9.4 install /Users/gaetano/Desktop/sqlite/node_modules/ursa
> node-gyp rebuild

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/ursaNative/src/ursaNative.o

Error output:
In file included from ../src/ursaNative.cc:3:
../src/ursaNative.h:13:10: fatal error: 'openssl/rsa.h' file not found
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/ursaNative/src/ursaNative.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:194:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 16.4.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/7.7.4/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/gaetano/Desktop/sqlite/node_modules/ursa
gyp ERR! node -v v7.7.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.5.0
gyp ERR! not ok 

npm ERR! Darwin 16.4.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/7.7.4/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "rebuild" "ursa"
npm ERR! node v7.7.4
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! ursa@0.9.4 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ursa@0.9.4 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the ursa package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs ursa
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls ursa
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/gaetano/Desktop/sqlite/npm-debug.log

    at ChildProcess.childProcess.once.code (/Users/gaetano/Desktop/sqlite/node_modules/electron-builder-util/src/util.ts:134:14)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:293:19)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:194:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:899:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:342:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:513:12)
From previous event:
    at spawn (/Users/gaetano/Desktop/sqlite/node_modules/electron-builder-util/src/util.ts:97:3)
    at /Users/gaetano/Desktop/sqlite/node_modules/electron-builder/src/yarn.ts:118:11
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at runCallback (timers.js:666:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:639:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:611:5)
```

i thought it was an error by node-gyp, so i've tryied installing int as global package, with no luck. 
reading all this weird errors, i saw it has something to do with ursa module, could it be?!

any help is apreciated :smiley:

Comment: `brew install openssl`

Comment: it doesen't work :(

Comment: Try downgrading python to 2.7 `conda install python=2.7.8` . It worked for me

Comment: Biro, did you ever find a way?

Comment: it was an issue with the version of electron-build and electron-updater. 
Updating everything makes it work for me..

Comment: ugh... I'm having the same issue. I'm running on MacOS

Comment: I've also installed python 2.7.8 but nothing seems to work. I need to rebuild so that I can properly use sqlite3